# Creating plot using R under Mac OS

Tags: r, macos, quartz

I use `R` in `Mac` through command line. When I need to draw some plot, R open plotting device called `Quartz` to display plot. It all works fine, but problem arise when I update a plot or draw a new plot based on changed plot. It looks like `Quartz` device does not automatically update the same. I need to close Quartz before I update my data and hit enter, so that new/modified plot can appear in `Quartz`.

I am wondering if this is default behaviour when `R` is run from command line in `Mac`? Is there any way to automatically update the plot in `Quartz` every time I update the data for plotting?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What types of plotting commands are you using? How exactly are you updating the plot. It's not clear at all what exactly you are doing. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: just simple plot. Say `dat = 1:3; plot(dat)` Next I write: `dat1 <- 10:30`, now when I type and enter `plot(dat1)` I still see 1st plot in my `Quartz` device unless I close before 2nd plot